# How to perform GreenPlum 6.x Backup & Recovery

Tags: database-backups, greenplum, wal

I am using **GreenPlum 6.x** and facing issues while performing backup and recovery. Does we have any tool to take the physical backup of whole cluster like pgbackrest for Postgres, further how can we purge the **WAL** of master and each segment as we can't take the pg_basebackup of whole cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using open source Greenplum 6 or a paid version?  If paid, you can download the gpbackup/gprestore parallel backup utility (separate from the database software itself) which will back up the whole cluster with a wide variety of options.  If using open source, your options are pretty much limited to pgdump/pgdumpall.

There is no way to purge the WAL logs that I am aware of.  In Greenplum 6, the WAL logs are used to keep all the individual postgres engines in sync throughout the cluster.   You would not want to purge these individually.

Jim McCann
VMware Tanzu Data Engineer

Comment: We are using the Open Source GreenPlum and our mount point is increasing day by day so how we can maintain the WAL logs

Answer (score 0):

I would like to better understand the the issues you are facing when you are performing your backup and recovery.

For Open Source user of the Greenplum Database, the gpbackup/gprestore utilities can be downloaded from the Releases page on the Github repo:

https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpbackup/releases

v1.19.0 is the latest.

There currently isn't a pg_basebackup / WAL based backup/restore solution for Greenplum Database 6.x

Answer (score 0):

WAL logs are periodically purged (as they get replicated to mirror and flushed) from master and segments individually. So, no manual purging is required. Have you looked into why the WAL logs are not getting purged? One of the reasons could be mirrors in cluster is down. If that happens WAL will continue mounting on primary and won't get purged. Perform `select * from pg_replication_slots;` for master or segment for which WAL is building to know more.

If the cause for WAL build is due replication slot as for some reason is mirror down, can use guc `max_slot_wal_keep_size` to configure max size WAL's should consume, after that replication slot will be disabled and not consume more disk space for WAL.

Comment: Currently we don't have any mirror and we are running as a standalone GP cluster without any standy/mirror is there any safe way through which we can discard the WAL files directly on the DB server.

Comment: Old WAL gets automatically deleted on checkpoints without mirrors. So, I am not sure why wish to manually discard the WAL files, it's not safe to manually delete the WAL files. Would be helpful to check how many WAL files you are seeing, are the files not being recycled at all with workload or number of WAL files just keeps growing.